# jquery code make more compact

Tags: jquery, function

Hi guys is was wondering if there is any other way to write the following query in a more compact format. Below you can see my code.

```
$('footer').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height:90}, 750);
        $('#up').stop().animate({opacity:0},450);
        $('#link-container').stop().animate({opacity:1},750);
        });
$('footer').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height:22}, 750);
        $('#up').stop().animate({opacity:1},450);
        $('#link-container').stop().animate({opacity:0},750);
        });
```

Comment: 10 lines of code. How much more compact do you think it's possible to make it? Don't waste time on micro-optimisation: go work on something more useful.

Comment: You can make it more concise using Google's Closure Compiler: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: Thank you @AndersonGreen that is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor the code into a function that takes parameters for the values that differ:

```
function anim(e, h, op) {
  $(e).stop().animate({height:h}, 750);
    $('#up').stop().animate({opacity:op},450);
    $('#link-container').stop().animate({opacity:1-op},750);
}
```

Then chain the two bindings:

```
$('footer').mouseover(function(){
  anim(this, 90, 0);
}).mouseout(function(){
  anim(this, 22, 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well you could chain the function bindings:

```
$('footer').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height:90}, 750);
        $('#up').stop().animate({opacity:0},450);
        $('#link-container').stop().animate({opacity:1},750);
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height:22}, 750);
        $('#up').stop().animate({opacity:1},450);
        $('#link-container').stop().animate({opacity:0},750);
});
```